# Nodejs mongoclient collection export

Tags: mongodb

This is connection.js

```
var MongoClient  = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db_singleton = null;

var getConnection= function getConnection(callback) {
    if (db_singleton) {
        callback(null,db_singleton);
    } else {
        var connURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb";
        MongoClient.connect(connURL,function(err,db){
            if(err)
                console.log("Error creating new connection "+err);
            else
            {
                db_singleton=db;
                console.log("created new connection");
            }
            callback(err,db_singleton);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = getConnection;
```

And this is product.js

```
var getConnection = require('../../connection.js');
var products = null;

getConnection(function(err,db) {
    var collection = db.collection("products");
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, productsDB) {
        products = productsDB;
    })
});
console.log(products);
module.export = products;
```

console.log(products) is always null.
But it should be object.I would like to cache variable when server starts.

Comment: Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194966/assign-mongoose-return-result-to-node-js-variable)