# Assign mongoose return result to node js variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node js and mongoose.I have the below code in node js. I wanted to assign the return `userData` record by the mongoose to variable `user` which is outside the callback.

```
var user = null;
User.findOne({$and: [{"_id": advisorId}, {"role": "advisor"}]}, {firstName:1,lastName:1, '_id':0},
    function(err,userData) {
        user = userData;
});
```

Once I have the return result in `user` variable I can directly pass it to the jade view as follow:

```
TrackSession.find({'advisor_id' : advisorId},fields,function(err, chatHistoryData) {
    var jade = require('jade');
    var html = jade.renderFile(appRoot+'/views/generatePDFHTML.jade', {'chatHistoryData': chatHistoryData,
        'selectedOptions':selectedOptions,
        'advisor':user,
        'tableHeaders':tableHeaders
    });
    console.log(html); return false;
});
```

But when I am trying to do this I am getting `null` as the value of the `user` variable. Is there any specific solution to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you put the render code inside the findOne() callback ?

Comment: Why are you passing in 'user' into the callback?  I think your hiding 'user' at the higher scope.

Comment: Opps it was by mistake , you can now check it I have edited the question.

Comment: @SarathNair: I have edited the question can you check the code once again. Actually, I want data with the user details. As unfortunately it is not supporting Relations mapping how could I get the data of the user by advisorId.

Comment: Remember that the callback that sets 'user' is asynchronous ... Alan beat me to it.

Comment: In your edited version, there is a chance that the find() callback of "TrackSession" executes after findOne() callback of  "User" and the rendering would work as expected. But it is still unstable, sometimes it might not work. You should put TrackSession inside of the findOne() callback, to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The callback of the findOne() is asynchronous, it gets executed after you get to rendering the jade. The execution jumps to "TrackSession" before the user variable gets a new value.

You should put the var html = ... inside the callback.

```js
var user = null;
User.findOne({$and: [{"_id": advisorId}, {"role": "advisor"}]},{firstName:1,lastName:1, '_id':0}, function(err,userData,user) {
        user = userData;
        
        TrackSession.find({'advisor_id' : advisorId},fields,function(err, chatHistoryData) {
        var jade = require('jade');
        var html = jade.renderFile(appRoot+'/views/generatePDFHTML.jade', {'chatHistoryData': chatHistoryData,
            'selectedOptions':selectedOptions,
            'advisor':user,
            'tableHeaders':tableHeaders
        });
        console.log(html); return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.